# Compute CG content of a gene sequence (percentage)

Tags: r

How can I calculate the CG content expressed in percentage of the following hypothetical DNA sequence?

```
secuencia <- sample(c("A","C","T","G"),60, 
  replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3))
```

Comment: `100 * sum(secuencia %in% c("C","G"))/length(secuencia)`

Comment: `table(secuencia)` the rest is simple division.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was useful

Comment: someone can post an answer ...